# Display data in new row using Excel VBA from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I want to display max(value) of the different oven in a column.

I tried working on it but it is overwriting the next max(value) and feeding it into the same cell instead of displaying it in different rows in the column.

```vb
Sub TakeDataFromServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim fld As ADODB.Field
    Dim mssql As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim ws As ThisWorkbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim colCount As Integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    startT = Sheet1.Cells(9, 1)
    endT = Sheet1.Cells(9, 5)

    For i = 9 To 12    
        oven = Mid(Sheet1.Cells(i, 9), 3, 1)
        Select Case oven
           Case Is = 1
              mssql = "select * from openquery(ihistorian,'set     starttime=08/07/2018,endtime=08/08/2018,intervalmilliseconds=60000,samplingmode=calculated,calculationmode=maximum select max(Value) from ihrawdata where tagname like fix.f1_load* and value <= 750 ')"

           Case Is = 2
              mssql = "select * from openquery(ihistorian,'set starttime=08/07/2018,endtime=08/08/2018,intervalmilliseconds=60000,samplingmode=calculated,calculationmode=maximum select max(Value) from ihrawdata where tagname like fix.f2_load* and value <= 750 ')"

           Case Is = 3
              mssql = "select * from openquery(ihistorian,'set starttime=08/07/2018,endtime=08/08/2018,intervalmilliseconds=60000,samplingmode=calculated,calculationmode=maximum select max(Value) from ihrawdata where tagname like fix.f3_load* and value <= 750 ')"

           Case Is = 4
              mssql = "select * from openquery(ihistorian,'set starttime=08/07/2018,endtime=08/08/2018,intervalmilliseconds=60000,samplingmode=calculated,calculationmode=maximum select max(Value) from ihrawdata where tagname like fix.f4_load* and value <= 750 ')"

           Case Is = 5
              mssql = "select * from openquery(ihistorian,'set starttime=08/07/2018,endtime=08/08/2018,intervalmilliseconds=60000,samplingmode=calculated,calculationmode=maximum select max(Value) from ihrawdata where tagname like fix.f5_load* and value <= 750 ')"

           Case Is = 6
              mssql = "select * from openquery(ihistorian,'set starttime=08/07/2018,endtime=08/08/2018,intervalmilliseconds=60000,samplingmode=calculated,calculationmode=maximum select max(Value) from ihrawdata where tagname like fix.f6_load* and value <= 750 ')"

       End Select

       MsgBox oven

       conn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.1.5.7;UID=sa;PWD=V&53zkd"
       conn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
       conn.Open

       rs.Open mssql, conn

       If rs.EOF Then
          MsgBox "No records found"
          rs.Close
          conn.Close
          Exit Sub
       End If

       row = 8
       Col = 29

       For rowCount = 1 To 4
          For colCount = 1 To 1
             For Each fld In rs.Fields
                Sheet1.Cells(row + rowCount, Col + colCount).Value = fld
             Next
          Next colCount 
       Next rowCount 
       rs.Close
       conn.Close
   Next i

End Sub
```

I want my output like this

```
606
649
606
644
```

but it is repeating the updated number

```
644
644
644
644
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

I just needed to figure out the row and column

If Not rs.EOF Then
 Sheet1.Cells(row, Col).Value = rs(0)
End If

row = row + 1